# Show different result depending on values user has chosen

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and trying to learn/find solution for case where user can choose multiple values and then different result is shown depending on values chosen.

I made jsfiddle where is three example results for three combination of values.

If user has chosen Name1, Name1 and Name1 from dropdowns then show result from div class **show-this-1**

And if values are Name2, Name2 and Name2 then show results from div class **show-this-2**

How to implement this?

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="Main" ng-app>
    <div>selections = {{selections}}</div>

    <div>
        <p>Select values</p>

        <select ng-model="selections[0]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="selections[1]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="selections[2]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="show-this-1">3x Name1 chosen</div>
    <div class="show-this-2">3x Name2 chosen</div>
    <div class="show-this-3">3x Name3 chosen</div>

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function Main($scope) {

$scope.selections = ["", "", ""];

$scope.sample = function() {
    $scope.selections = [ "id-1", "id-2", "id-3" ];
}

$scope.items = [{
    id: 'id-1',
    name: 'Name 1'},
{
    id: 'id-2',
    name: 'Name 2'},
{
    id: 'id-3',
    name: 'Name 3'}];
}
```

[jsfiddle Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/2JWb2/1059/)

Comment: You didn't clearly ask what you want. What result do you want to show?

Comment: basicly i would push the values in and the if $scope.selection.length == 3 then u show the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only one out of three divs depending whether user has selected the same option in all three dropdowns then the answer would be:

```
<div ng-controller="Main" ng-app>
    <div>selections = {{selections}}</div>

    <div>
        <p>Select values</p>

        <select ng-model="selections[0]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="selections[1]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="selections[2]" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="show-this-1" ng-show="selections[0] == items[0].id && selections[1] == items[0].id && selections[2] == items[0].id">3x Name1 chosen</div>
        <div class="show-this-2" ng-show="selections[0] == items[1].id && selections[1] == items[1].id && selections[2] == items[1].id">3x Name2 chosen</div>
        <div class="show-this-3" ng-show="selections[0] == items[2].id && selections[1] == items[2].id && selections[2] == items[2].id">3x Name3 chosen</div>
     </div>

</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz0pLsyn/)